# SP2013 - Can I change the PageLayout for System Pages outside of Publishing Pages?

Tags: 2013, master-page, publishing, layouts

I don't want to apply my page layout on the system pages of my sharepoint site (eg. site settings..). This function is a available within a publishing site.

However, other site templates do not support this setting.

Why is this disabled and how can I enable this functionality for other site templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable the Publishing feature on Site Collection feature and Manage Site feature. This will enable the functionality of a Publishing site.

Comment: This is correct - and to clarify further, the publishing feature does not require the site to use a publishing site template. It can be enabled on a team site, for example.

Comment: This answer is correct, however you need to navigate to "/_layouts/15/changesitemasterpage.aspx" to change the masterpage, as it is not listed in site settings.